# Upper bounds on the approximate inverse of a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a *singular* matrix and $\zeta>0$ such that $A+\zeta I$ is nonsingular.

**Soft question:** Is it true that if $\zeta$ is sufficiently small, then $$(A+\zeta I)^{-1}A \approx I$$ (or $A(A+\zeta I)^{-1} \approx I$)?

**More precisely:** Let $E:=(A+\zeta I)^{-1}A - I$. If the answer to the above (soft) question is "yes", what are some known bounds on $E$?

*Note.* Using the condition number $\kappa(A)$, a well-known bound is 
$$
\frac{\Vert(A+B)^{-1} - A^{-1}\Vert}{\Vert A^{-1}\Vert}
\le \kappa(A)\frac{\Vert B\Vert}{\Vert A\Vert },
$$

but this bound requires that both $A$ and $A+B$ are nonsingular. In my question, $A$ is *singular* while $A+B$ is nonsingular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try some trivial test cases, like
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\implies A(A+\zeta I)^{-1}=\pmatrix{(1+ζ)^{-1}&0\\0&0}
$$
which is nowhere close to the identity matrix.

Comment: I wonder if it generally converges to the projection on the range, as it does for your example.  I suspect that this generally holds when $A$ is symmetric, at least.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @JohnA would a result that applies only to symmetric matrices be useful?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, but I would also be interested in how you are connecting this question with the range projection of $A$ more generally (even if there isn't a precise theorem or proof available).

Answer (score 3):

There must exist *some* bound on $E$. But it's not true that $||E||\to0$ as $\zeta\to0$, which would seem to say that the answer to  the slightly fuzzy question of whether $(A+\zeta I)^{-1}A \approx I$ is no:

There exists $x\ne0$ with $Ax=0$. Hence $Ex=-x$, so $||E||\ge1$.

Answer (score 3):

When $A$ is diagonalizable, we can find a change of basis $S$ such that $M = S^{-1}AS$ is diagonal, and moreover
$$
M = \pmatrix{D & 0\\0 &0}
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal and invertible matrix.  We see that
$$
M(M + \zeta I)^{-1} = \pmatrix{D(D + \zeta I)^{-1} & 0\\0 &0}.
$$
As $\zeta \to 0$, we see that $M(M + \zeta I)^{-1}$ approaches the projection onto the range of $M$ along the kernel of $M$.  Since we merely applied a change of basis, we can conclude that $A(A + \zeta I)^{-1}$ approaches the projection $P$ onto the range of $A$ along the kernel of $A$.

That is, $A(A + \zeta I)^{-1} \to P$ where $P$ satisfies:

- $P^2 = P$
- $PAx = Ax$ for all $x$
- $Px = 0 \iff Ax = 0$

---

In general, $A(A + \zeta I)^{-1}$ approaches the projection onto the image of $A^n$ along the kernel of $A^n$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix.  This holds whether or not $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: What is meant by "projection onto the range of A *along the kernel of A*"?

Comment: That’s what the explanation about $P$ explains

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hmmm it seems $(A+\zeta I)^{-1}\to A^+$, the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_inverse) of $A$...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform my first thought was something involving the pseudo inverse as well.  However, $AA^+$ is an orthogonal projection, which is not generally true for the limit of $A(A + \zeta I)^{-1}$, so we can rule that out.  I think your idea holds for symmetric matrices, though

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform $(A^*A+\zeta I)^{-1}A^* \to A^+$; see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6882.pdf